# If my PS Plus account expires, do my free packs expire as well?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus, tera

I know you lose free games, such as the free monthly games, when your Plus expires. But what about the free packs you've downloaded?

I have Tera — a free game you can get without PS Plus, and since I have PS Plus right now, I decided to get the PS Plus exclusive free Valkyrie pack that has the costume, an extra character slot and a wolf mount that I desperately wanted back since I got it on the PC version.

My question is, since I obtained the pack and I have the items bonded to my character, what happens the moment Plus expires? Do they disappear from my inventory? Do I keep them regardless? Do I lose my ability to play the game all together despite the game itself being a free game for non-plus users?

Answer (score 2):

If you go by this recent news post: https://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/gaming/1180787/PS-Plus-October-Free-Games-Great-PS4-PlayStation-September-21

> World of Tanks fans can grab the exclusive PS+ Silver Drop right now
>   on the PlayStation Store.
>
> And unlike the free PS Plus games offered each month, all items
>   included remain part of your account, even if you end your
>   subscription in the future.

Tera would be the same case here. I don't think Sony would be able to track and disable all ps plus packs offered by different games.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it is not gone forever, when you renew your account you will also regain access to the content that you have previously downloaded through PlayStation plus. so yes and no. hopefully I was able to help.

Comment: This is true for games downloaded, but as seen above, additional content is kept unlocked.